# Android gradle - Setting up product flavors using different directories for config files, looks in all directories rather than just 1

Tags: android, firebase, gradle

For an existing app that's moving over to firebase I'm trying to set up a development build and a production build. I'm using two different projects in firebase and as such have two different google.services.json. I'm mostly followed [this example](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/organizing-your-firebase-enabled-android-app-builds.html).

Stripped Gradle file, note the buildTypes & productFlavors :

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "nl.my_project.cwo_app"
        (...)
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
        }
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        }
    }


    // This is used to ensure the right version of google-services.json is used.
    flavorDimensions "version"
    productFlavors {
        dev {
            dimension "version"
            versionNameSuffix "-dev"
        }
        prod {
            dimension "version"
            versionNameSuffix "-prod"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
     ...
}
```

I have the following directory structure:

```
app/
    src/
        main/
        dev/
            google-services.json (for dev only)
        prod/
            google-services.json (for prod only)
```

As far as I understand this should make sure that once I build anything with the dev flavor that it uses the google-services.json in the dev folder. But when I build the project (after selecting a build variant, for example devDebug) it gives an error saying the application ID does not fit. Looking into this shows that in fact BOTH google-services.json are being used. How can I change this?

The build log:

```
14:00:55: Executing task 'build'...

Executing tasks: [build]


> Configure project :app

> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preDevDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDevDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
(...) 

> Task :app:processDevDebugGoogleServices
Parsing json file: E:\projecten\CWO_app\app\src\dev\google-services.json

(...)     
> Task :app:processProdDebugGoogleServices FAILED
Parsing json file: E:\projecten\CWO_app\app\src\prod\google-services.json

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
Execution failed for task ':app:processProdDebugGoogleServices'.
> No matching client found for package name 'nl.my_project.cwo_app.debug'
```

As you can see it creates a version with the applicationIdSuffix ".debug" and then tries to match that to the file in the 'prod' folder, which doesn't use that applicationId. How can I stop it from looking at both folders?

Comment: did you have debug and release folders in your src?

Comment: No I don't, as far as I know this isn't required. But I don't know a lot about this.

Comment: I have same case, and I create structure like `src\release\dev\google-services.json`  and `src\release\prod\google-services.json` and same for `src\debug\...` it works for me

Comment: Thanks for the input. I've tried this, building devDebug, and get the same error now for the folder: debug\prod\google-services.json. So it's still going into folders it shouldn't get.

Comment: Try with my structure and remove `applicationIdSuffix ".debug"` from debug in buildTypes

Comment: and if you need to add debug as different app you need to add this line back `applicationIdSuffix ".debug"` and add new app to your firebase app settings like nl.my_project.cwo_app.debug and change current json in src\debug\dev\google-services.json

Comment: tell me if it works

Answer (score 0):

The problem relays on the combination between flavor and release names. According to the provided gradle file, when the build type is "debug", then the suffix `.debug` is added, hence if your `google-services.json` file doesn't have the declared resulting package name, then will fail.

The available package name combinations are:

- `nl.my_project.cwo_app.debug` (for debug build type)
- `nl.my_project.cwo_app` (for release build type)

**How to fix this**

Check in your `google-services.json` the available package names. If any of the combinations described above are not declared there, then add them from the Firebase console and update the new json file into your project.

Tip:
You can have one single `google-services.json` file with all the package names in it instead of having one file per combination of flavor and/or build. Regularly, this is more neat in terms of maintainability (one file vs build types * number of flavors)